# Microsoft.Graph library required permission for application AddPassword and RemovePassword

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to add and remove passwords with the Microsoft.graph library.

```
graphServiceClient.Applications[app.Id]
.AddPassword(pwc)
.Request()
.PostAsync();
```

And

```
graphServiceClient.Applications[app.Id].RemovePassword(oldPassword.KeyId.Value).Request().PostAsync();
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
> Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Which api permission do I need for this? I already have Application.ReadWrite.All. But still getting this error.

Comment: Could you try to add Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission?

Comment: In python I had this issue when i was communicating against the wrong API. I i don't quite remember all the details, but in the portal I remember that the permissions I needed to assign were those of the legacy api. (Azure Active Directory Graph) And in my python code I had to specify the AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD to be used: AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory_graph_resource_id -- You can see that it is not connecting to Graph endpoint. Perhaps you are using permissions for one endpoint, but are connecting towards the other and thus get the insufficient permissions error.

Comment: Directory.AccessAsUser.All did not solve the problem. I can get user or application data. But simply adding or removing passwords is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other people who run into the same issue, Application.ReadWrite.All was the permission I needed. I tried this permission before, but didn't set it as application type.